# read.bmp image using qdbmp

Tags: python, c, image, bmp

I am using a library called qdbmc to read a bmp gray image (lena_gray.bmp)

this the [link](http://qdbmp.sourceforge.net/) to the library

and this is my code:

```
int read_image(char *filename)
{
struct _BMP* bmp;
UINT    width, height;
UCHAR red,green,blue;

bmp = BMP_ReadFile(filename);
BMP_CHECK_ERROR( stderr, -1 );

/* Get image's dimensions */
 width = BMP_GetWidth( bmp );
 height = BMP_GetHeight( bmp );
 printf("%lu   %lu \n",width,height);

 /* Iterate through all the image's pixels */
 for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; ++x )
 {
     for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; ++y )
     {
         /* Get pixel's RGB values */
         BMP_GetPixelRGB( bmp, x, y, &red, &green, &blue );
         printf("%d \t %d \t %d \n",red,green,blue);
     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

the width and the height are displayed correctly (512 x 512) but the pixels values are in correct because it is showing me all zeros.

when i used the imread() function with python i got this :

```
60 160 160 159 161 156 161 159 162 159 160 158 154 162 158 154 156 155
160 160 153 156 154 156 154 156 154 152 155 153 153 155 153 157 155 158
.....
```

can someone please help?

## edit

This is the [link to the image](http://eeweb.poly.edu/%7Eyao/EL5123/SampleData.html) (choose Lena, 8 bit gray (512 x 512), bmp
)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the `"%lu"` format specifier is for `unsigned long int`. The variables `width` and `height` are `unsigned int`, for which you should not use the `l` prefix in the format specifier.

Comment: well it was the compiler that suggested me to change it ... but you are right

Comment: @Some programmer dude Actually the documentation for the library says that `UINT` is a `UINT - Unsigned long integer (DWORD)`

Comment: Maybe the format of the bmp image is not supported by the library, it supports Uncompressed 32 BPP, Uncompressed 24 BPP and Uncompressed 8 BPP. You have to be sure your image is in one of these forms.

Comment: UINT is normally unsigned int - for reference. A SDR - is your image uncompressed - or raw?

Comment: @малинчекуров And are you sure the OP is using `UINT` from the library? If the OP is using Windows system headers then the OP is probably using [the Windows `UINT` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#UINT), which is a 32-bit type.

Comment: @Some programmer dude he said his compiler suggested him to use `lu`, so I think it's clear he is using the `UINT` from the library.

Comment: @малинчекуров Then yes probably. And this is the reason why libraries should never define their own aliases for common types, it's highly confusing.

Comment: We are getting off topic, the main reason for the problem must be the library doesn't understand that bmp image variant.

Comment: Is this the same BMP file as in your other question, because that doesn't look like a valid BMP file as I already said... https://stackoverflow.com/q/50333239/2836621

Comment: no not the same

Comment: Please add a hex or octal dump of the first few bytes of your image file. Or better still, share the entire file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i added a link to the image

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i corrected the link .... sorry

Comment: Could you please post a **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example** as required by Stack Overflow - that means the simplest **complete** program that reproduces the error - including `main()` and `#includes`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither output is correct. Gray colors in grayscale bitmap are of the form: (x,x,x) where the red, blue, and green are the same. Therefore zero is wrong. And and `60 160 160 159 161 156 ...` is wrong because there is no repeat pattern.

8-bit bitmap uses a table. The first 54 bytes are the file heading. Then there is 256 colors (each 4 bytes long) and then width * height bytes, where width has to be padded so the size of width in bytes is a multiple of 4.

The bitmap pixels start from bottom to top, first you have to read the row (starting from bottom) then read each column. This code should print the correct output for the first 5 columns in each row:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct my_BITMAPFILEHEADER {
    short bfType;
    int bfSize;
    short bfReserved1;
    short bfReserved2;
    int bfOffBits;
};

struct my_BITMAPINFOHEADER {
    int biSize;
    int biWidth;
    int biHeight;
    short biPlanes;
    short biBitCount;
    int biCompression;
    int biSizeImage;
    int biXPelsPerMeter;
    int biYPelsPerMeter;
    int biClrUsed;
    int biClrImportant;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(void)
{
    if(sizeof(struct my_BITMAPFILEHEADER) != 14)
    {
        printf("stop!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\test\\barbara_gray.bmp", "rb");

    //Read file header
    struct my_BITMAPFILEHEADER fhdr;
    struct my_BITMAPINFOHEADER ihdr;
    fread(&fhdr, sizeof(fhdr), 1, fp);
    fread(&ihdr, sizeof(ihdr), 1, fp);

    if(fhdr.bfType == 'MB' && ihdr.biBitCount == 8 && ihdr.biPlanes == 1)
    {
        //Read table
        unsigned int table[256] = { 0 };
        fread(table, 4, 256, fp);

        int w = ihdr.biWidth;
        int h = ihdr.biHeight;

        //Find width in bytes. Use a math trick to make sure it's divisble by 4
        int w_in_bytes = ((w * 8 + 31) / 32) * 4;
        int size = w_in_bytes * h;

        //Read pixels
        unsigned char *pixels = malloc(size);
        fread(pixels, 1, size, fp);

        //Read from bottom to top:
        for(int row = h - 1; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            printf("%3d: ", h - 1 - row);
            //Read from left to right:
            for(int col = 0; col < w; col++)
            {
                int pos = row * w_in_bytes + col;
                unsigned char color_index = pixels[pos];
                unsigned int clr = table[color_index];
                printf("%02X%02X%02X ", 
                    clr & 0xFF, (clr >> 8) & 0xFF, (clr >> 16) & 0xFF);
                if(col > 5) break;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        free(pixels);
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```