# Retrieving LPBITMAPINFOHEADER from a bitmap (c++)

Tags: c++, file-io, bitmap

So I have a .bmp file. I need to retrieve the header LPBITMAPINFOHEADER from the file.

```
FILE *sFile = 0;
sFile = fopen("myfile.bmp", "rb");
```

What do I do next?

I'm really lost in all the stuff I was able to google so would really appreciate any help!

Comment: This has all you need. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: Is this operating system specific? In Windows for example you have specific functions for this. Or look at this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50362304/4603670) for a more general version.

Comment: See [Bitmap Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183391.aspx) on MSDN.